# How to let users mark ( like) other users?

Tags: users

In my project I'd like to let users to mark (kinda like) other users.

What solution should I use? Appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module. It does have integration with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module. So you can configure and customize.

> Flag is a flexible flagging system that is completely customizable by
>   the administrator. Using this module, the site administrator can
>   provide any number of flags for nodes, comments, users, and any other
>   type of entity. Some possibilities include bookmarks, marking
>   important, friends, or flag as offensive. With extensive views
>   integration, you can create custom lists of popular content or keep
>   tabs on important content.
>
> Flags may be per-user, meaning that each user can mark an item
>   individually, or global, meaning that the item is either marked or it
>   is not marked, and any user who changes that changes it for everyone.
>
> In this way, additional flags (similar to published and sticky) can be
>   put on nodes, or other items, and dealt with by the system however the
>   administration likes.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module as suggested in the previous answer is indeed the typical solution to answer this question. If you're not familiar with the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module, checkout the [set of 8 video tutorials](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-flag) about the flag module.

However, often times, depending on your specific case, some of the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) related modules are usefull also, such as (partial list):

- [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), to create lists of flagged content, users, etc, such as in the video about [Creating global flags and listing flagged content in Views](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/creating-global-flags-and-listing-flagged-content-in-views).
- [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), to trigger rules for anything that is flagged, such as in the video about [Triggering rules with Flag](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/triggering-rules-with-flag), or to set flags with the Rules module, such as in the video about [Setting flags with Rules](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/setting-flags-with-rules).
- [Flag Lists](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_lists), to allow users to create custom lists.
- [Flag Weights](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_weights), to add weights to Flags (to be used for sorting).
- [DraggableViews](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews), to make Views draggable (so that they can be rearranged by Drag'n'Drop.).
- [Flag Friend](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_friend), a pre-built flag for marking other users as friends (using the Flag module).
- [Flag Abuse](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_abuse), a pre-built flag for marking offensive content, with some extra administrative features.
- [Flag, Hide & Mute](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_hide), for users to hide individual nodes, such as site-wide announcements or advertisements, and/or to suppress all posts by users they do not want to see.
- [Flag Files](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_files), to flag media files.
- [Flag Service](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_service), to allow Flag to be accessed via a web services interface through the Services module.
- [DLike](https://www.drupal.org/project/dlike), provides a Facebook like "Like" functionality using the Flag and Lightbox2 module.
- [Conditional Flags](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_flags), provides an extra API to Flag module, for custom conditions between flags.
- [Organic Groups Flag Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/og_flag), extends the flag module with organic groups support allowing the administrators of each group to override the global flag settings for their group.
- [Context Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_flag), allows the use of Flags as conditional triggers for use with the [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module.

Refer to its [community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/flag) for way more details.